# OpenPGP Encryption Using BouncyCastle Lightweight API

Tags: java, encryption, aes, bouncycastle, pgp

I have to encrypt some content using a 256 bit AES-CBC key. The encryption protocol to be followed is OpenPGP. Since the key size is 256 bit and the public/private keys will also be of 4096 bit I will have to use the lightweight APIs. I have found several questions that show how to encrypt using a 256 bit AES-CBC key but I cannot figure out how to integrate that with PGP.

The most obvious approach is to encrypt it using the AES engine and then encrypt the result using the public key as it is done in OpenPGP. However that would require me to generate the initialization vectors and the AES keys. These are things that I would prefer the library to do since there are a lot of things that can go wrong while doing it.

Here is a sample of the code I am using to encrypt:

```
PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encGen = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(new JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder(PGPEncryptedData.AES_256).setWithIntegrityPacket(true).setSecureRandom(rand).setProvider("BC"));
    encGen.addMethod(new JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(<PGPPublic Key object>));

    OutputStream encryptedOut = encGen.open(out, new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]);
```

From looking at the code for the open function I have determined that the input stream is first encoded using AES-CFB (the library handles all of the above issues I have mentioned with the Initialization Vectors internally) and then using the public key that I have provided. How do I get it to use AES-CBC instead?

Comment: Why do the key sizes force you to use the lightweight APIs?

Comment: As far as I know, the unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files are needed if we need aes key sizes of 256 bits. My use case does not allow that since it is not a portable solution.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Unlimited strength does require fiddling with the JRE directory, and that isn't always feasible.

Comment: So the issue remains the same. How do I build a PGP encrypted file using a custom symmetric algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question mostly boils down to two parts -- using AES-256 and switching to the CBC mode of operation. I cannot help you with using AES-256 in Bouncy Castle, but can provide clarifications regarding the mode of operation.

You cannot use CBC with OpenPGP. The OpenPGP specification only allows a [special variant of CFB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-13.9). If you require CBC, you'll have to choose another crypto system; if putting together OpenPGP messages is more important, stick to the OpenPGP CFB mode. If you create OpenPGP messages in CBC mode, they're not following the standard and other implementations of OpenPGP (like PGP, "normal" BouncyCastle" and GnuPG) will not be able to read the message.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As a follow up, if I could modify the source code in bouncy castle to use CBC, are there any security vulnerabilities that I should worry about? I know that changing the block mode is functionally equivalent to creating a new protocol itself and testing for vulnerabilities in it is a very broad topic. I just wanted to know if someone has already done such a thing because it seems to me that surely other modes would have been considered while designing the protocol

Comment: If you're not very sure about cryptography and discuss any changes wiith peers in science, don't do them. History of cryptography (including the beginnings of PGP) are _full_ of people trying to do clever stuff and failing miserably. If you need advanced security, don't roll out your own crypto. If you need CBC, don't go for OpenPGP. Don't write crypto code, don't change crypto protocols. This is far beyond the original question's scope anyway, and surely off topic for Stack Overflow in addition.