# Manually generate a PGP message

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, pgp

This is an extension of this question: [OpenPGP Encryption Using BouncyCastle Lightweight API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645113/pgp-encryption-using-bouncycastle-lightweight-api)

My problem is as follows:

I have to generate a PGP encrypted message from a plain text. Because of the key sizes in question the only options I had was to either install the Unlimited Strength policy files or use the lightweight API. Given that I needed the solution to be portable I decided to use the lightweight API.

All solutions that I have found to use the lightweight API use the PGPEncryptedDataGenerator and open a stream to encrypt it (code samples in the other link) however the AES encryption for it uses CFB mode whereas I need to do it in CBC mode.

My Current Approach:

I generated a random 256 bit key and 128 bit initialization vector and used it to encrypt the plaintext. Then I encrypted the key with the public key using RSA. I first wrote the encrypted key and then the encrypted text in a stream, signed it using a private key, created PGPLiteralDataPackets out of it and then compressed and armoured it.
However when I try to decrypt it using gpg, it recognized the private key I signed it with and then it gives me a set of non printable ascii characters, which means that it does not recognize the encrypted part even though the public key is present in its keyring.

This means that I am not constructing the message properly. I would like to know how to construct a PGP message manually using bouncy castle so that the encrypted message created by me will be recognized and decrypted.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the PGP file format and protocol, but after changing from CFB to CBC, have you set a flag somewhere which mode to use? What if PGP doesn't support CBC at all? That would probably mean that you cannot check compatibility with existing software.

Comment: I think testing an implementation against the **Open**PGP protocol is - well - slightly too broad.

Comment: I'm also voting to close this as too broad for the very same reason. Anyway, I provided an answer to your original question that also explains why you're getting unreadable plain text -- but might not be the only issue you're having right now.

Comment: You are correct in that. Upon looking at the source code for the library I saw that there were a lot of things that the library was doing but I was not such as creating and signing the headers, session keys etc. I did not take into consideration all the moving parts that the library handles for me internally because of which I was led to believe that this was a to the point question. However, considering these new factors, I agree with your estimation that this question is too broad. I am flagging it for the moderators.